# Log out from SSO kerberos

Tags: macos, single-sign-on, kerberos

My OSX application is required for authentication based on Kerberos protocol.
For login I'm using WebView (and WKWebView for MAC OSX > 10.9) by load the authorization URL request.

The login works as expected, but it remains logged in until I log out from my computer or killing my application.
It means that at the next time I load the authorization URL request then I logged in automatically without being promoted to insert my user & password.

Before I load the authorization URL I delete the cookies from  [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].

How can I log out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution is to close my application by:

[NSApp terminate:self];

A better solution will be to relaunch the app but this is enough for me right now.

Answer (score 5):

You need to destroy the kerberos tickets on the machine the web browser is running on.

```
/usr/bin/kdestroy
```

OS X used to have a graphical interface for managing tickets, but I think that is long gone. You should only be doing this for testing. Kerberos tickets are shared among many applications in OS X and if your app blows away the ticket, your users will come after you with pitchforks...

Comment: The old Kerberos GUI app is dead, but it's been replaced by Ticket Viewer (hidden in /System/Library/CoreServices/) which does most of the same things.

Comment: @Fred-the-magic-wonder-d
I executed the kdestroy and it finished with:
kdestroy: krb5_cc_destroy: No credentials cache file found

@ Gordon-Davisson
The Ticket Viewer is empty

I think that the solution should come from my application, specific my WebView, because as I said when I relaunch the application then I promoted to insert user & password.

Any advise?